# Python PLY parsing : definition scope

Tags: python, parsing, grammar, abstract-syntax-tree

I'm using PLY to parse files containing nested blocks.
Typically :

```
a {
    b {

    }
    c {
        d {

        }
    }    
}
```

I am using a simple grammar like so :

```
def p_nodes(p):
    '''
    nodes : node nodes
          | node
    '''
    # ??

def p_node(p):
    '''
    node : IDENTIFIER OPEN_CURLY_BRACE node_çontent CLOSE_CURLY_BRACE
    '''
    p[0] = Node(p[3])#FIXME?

def p_node_content(p):
    '''
    node_content : nodes
                 |
    '''
    if len(p) > 1:
        p[0] = p[1]
    else
        p[0] = None
```

I would like to know I could be able to access a 'parent' node in the parser. In other terms how can I build the AST so that I can retrieve in my example that `d` is a child of `c` which is itself child of `a` since I have to visibility to parent rule in the parser.

What should i put in `p_nodes` and `p_node` so that a valid AST can be built ? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We would have need your `Node` class, but I presume it is something like:

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, children):
        self.children = children
        self.type = None
```

Then your parser could look like that:

```
def p_nodes(p):
    '''
    nodes : node nodes
          | node
    '''
    if len(p) > 2:
        p[0] = [p[1]] + p[2]
    else
        p[0] = [p[1]] 

def p_node(p):
    '''
    node : IDENTIFIER OPEN_CURLY_BRACE node_content CLOSE_CURLY_BRACE
    '''
    p[0] = Node(p[3])

def p_node_content(p):
    '''
    node_content : nodes
                 |
    '''
    if len(p) > 1:
        p[0] = p[1]
    else
        p[0] = None
```

Then you will have a real AST, with each node containing a reference to all its childs.

Eventually, if you want your node to have a reference to their parent, you have to iterate on all the AST from the root and set it as an attribute on all his children, then do the same on it's children...

To do that, change your `Node` class to look like this:

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, children):
        self.children = children
        self.parent = None

    def set_parent(self, parent):
        self.parent = parent
```

And run a similar function as this:

```
def set_parent_to_AST(root_node):
    for node in root_node.children:
        node.set_parent(root_node)
        set_parent_to_AST(node)
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the parser does not allow things like `p[0] = Node(p[3], p[0])`. Moreover I do not see either how I could do this after the creation of the AST if the information has not been collected during its creation.

What also getting me stuck is that the rule `nodes : node nodes | node` implies that all `node` rules produced at this level have to be sibling nodes in the AST and it seems difficult to do it without a "scope" notion since at the parser level there is a recursion, and at the AST level these nodes have to be at a same depth.

Comment: I've update my answer, that should do what you want. Tell me if you still have some questions.

Comment: Ok this works perfectly, you saved my week-end, thank you very much ! The `p[0] = [p[1]] + p[2]` notation was exactly what I was missing.